# Meaning of wavevector in SSH model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, topological-insulators

If we solve the hamiltonian of the following form in the SSH model,

[image]

[image]

You will get an eigen vector of the following form.

[image]

[image]

I am having difficulty interpreting this eigen vector.
According to this eigen vector, the probability of there being a particle at A site seems to be fixed at 1/2, but I don't understand this part.
How can I find the number of cases where particles exist in A site and B site?

Comment: Please use MathJax for math.

Comment: Downvote for not using mathjax, here is a tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

For any $k$, the two eigenstates are distributed equally (in the sense of probability density) between the $A$ and $B$ sublattices. It's not clear to me exactly what your question is - if you had a vector which had no probability amplitude on the $A$ sublattice, for example, it certainly wouldn't be an eigenvector of the Hamiltonian because the standard SSH Hamiltonian consists *entirely* of terms which map the $A$ sublattice to the $B$ sublattice or vice-versa.